# Unable to find how to add a data source

Tags: monitoring, grafana, opentsdb

I have three node Hadoop cluster with Hbase. I have also configured OpenTSDB. At the moment I would like to connect it with Grafana v5.3.1. On [the official website](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/opentsdb/) there is written:

> Open the side menu by clicking the Grafana icon in the top header. In
>   the side menu under the Dashboards link you should find a link named
>   Data Sources.

However I don't have link named Data Sources and I can't find anywhere `+ Add data source`. Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: *Open the side menu by clicking the Grafana icon in the top header*... Show an image of what happens when you do this

Comment: @cricket_007 https://imgur.com/a/P9W53o6

Comment: And if you click on the plus icon in the top left there?

Comment: @cricket_007 The problem was that I was logged in as a user not as admin.

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you know whether there is a metric which shows number of rows in hbase table or alternatively number of rows in all tables in hbase?

Comment: I don't have experience with Hbase sorry. That should be a separate post rather than a comment

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to be logged in as admin
2. click on the gear
3. select "data sources"
4. click "add data source"

or use the link (change servername and port)

```
http://<grafana server>:3000/datasources
```

Comment: Do you know whether there is a metric which shows number of rows in hbase table or alternatively number of rows in all tables in hbase?

Comment: is your question answered? please mark is as such. if you have a new question please create a new question.